# How to paste only the formatted value not the actual value

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2016, text-formatting

As the title says, I want to copy and paste cells into the format that they are shown in.

**Original value (actual value):**

```
25
59,05
90,1
```

**Formatted value (what is shown):**

```
25,000
59,050
90,100
```

**The output value I want, not formatted:**

```
25,000
59,050
90,100
```

How do I do this?

I almost found the answer to this [here](https://www.mrexcel.com/board/threads/how-to-paste-only-the-formatted-value-not-the-actual-value.126631/) but it still removes trailing zeros.

Answer (score 2):

Copy the cells, paste them in Word. Copy back from Word to Excel.

Just thought of this after a few minutes of Googling / not finding any solution...

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Copying the format rather than the value is done like this :

- Select the source cell and do <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>
- Select the target cell
- In the Home pane, click the down-arrow of Paste (Clipboard group)
- Select Paste Special...
- Under Paste, click Formats
- Click OK.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible by just copy and pasting.
You need to make a Text() formula with the same number format as in your cell. That you can copy and past as VALUES.

If you need a different outcome, you need to adjust the "number format" ("#,000") in the text formula.,

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Copy the column to notepad. Save as text file. Open new sheet and in Data menu choose "From Text" choose the notepad file and then copy + paste to desired column in original sheet.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).